# jQuery UI tabs, update url for dynamic tabs

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI **dynamic** tabs for my application. I want to update the URL hash value when a user clicks on a tab.

I found some solutions on SO such as [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777518/jquery-ui-tabs-update-url-when-clicking-on-a-different-tab) 
and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023689/opening-jquery-tabs-with-url-and-adding-a-hash-to-url-on-tab-click) .

The solution that i tried is as follows:

Javascript:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {                   
        window.location.hash = ui.tab.hash;

        if ( ui.index == 0) // its preloaded
                return;                               
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs" > 
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1"   > Tab 1  </a></li>
        <li><a href="Home/Test1"> Tab 2  </a></li>
        <li><a href="Home/Test2"> Tab 3  </a></li>            
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        Some Text
    </div>
</div>
```

This solution takes the `href` value to update the URL. Thus for the first tab, URL hash becomes `#tabs-1`. However for other tabs, URL hash are: `#ui-tabs-1` and `#ui-tabs-2`.

I want the url hash value to be `#Employee` instead of `#ui-tabs-1`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried several ways. The easiest way that I found is to add a `name` property to the anchor element. 
So, the HTML part is as follows.

```
<div id="tabs" > 
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1"   > Tab 1  </a></li>
        <li><a name ="Employee" href="Home/Test1"> Tab 2  </a></li>
        <li><a name ="Address"  href="Home/Test2"> Tab 3  </a></li>            
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        Some Text
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript part will remain the same.